# Why does my python freeze when I use zip()?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, generator

I'm using Keras with a tensorflow backend. I need to extract a bunch of images from a directory, both inputs and outputs and use them to fit a model. I am using the [ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) function from the Keras library to create two generators, one that extracts the input files and one that extract the output files.

The Keras model.fit_generator() function only takes one generator, so I used the zip(generator_1, generator_2) to merge it into one generator. However, this resulted in my program freezing and never finishing.

```
def fit_model(self, batch_size, epochs, initial_epoch, callbacks):
    short_generator = self.train_datagen.flow_from_directory('../screenshots/short', class_mode=None, target_size=(self.x_res,self.y_res))
    long_generator = self.train_datagen.flow_from_directory('../screenshots/long', class_mode=None, target_size=(self.x_res,self.y_res))
    print('zipping generators')
    generator = zip(short_generator, long_generator)
    print('done zipping generators')
    self.model.fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(1190/self.batch_size), epochs=10)
    self.model.save('./weights/finished.h5')
```

This results in 'zipping generators' to print, but never 'done zipping generators'

Comment: Are you using Python 2.X?

Comment: @SergeiLebedev Yes, I posted this question because the issue plagued me for hours, and I wanted to explain it for anyone else who was stuck. I wasn't sure if there was an easier way to answer my own question, so sorry if I messed up somehow. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue and would like to explain to anyone else how:

I don't know if this is always true, but for me, zip() was freezing because it was running in Python 2.7. In Python 3.x, it literally runs in a second or two. I didn't uninstall Python 2, but I downloaded all the dependencies I needed in their Python 3 forms by doing:

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu, keras, numpy, etc...
```

Then I called the script by

```
python3 myscript.py
```

Instead of

```
python myscript.py
```

and it worked beautifully.

Comment: ...and that's because in Python 2, `zip` _is not_ a generator. It puts all the resulting data in memory, which may take a long time

Answer (score 1):

You could've solved your issue without switching to 3.X by replacing `zip` with [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).

`zip` in Python 2.X is eager and returns a list, whereas `itertools.izip` (which became `zip` in Python 3.X`) produces a lazy sequence.

Comment: Interesting, I still am confused how zip returning a list would freeze my function. The second print statement never gets called so it clearly never finished. Is the list too large? Each generator only had 1300 images.

Comment: In general, zip should've indeed returned a list or failed with a `MemoryError`. The  precise answer depends on the implementation details of `flow_from_directory`. E.g. it could produce a cyclic or repeated dataset (which is normal for training).